# HTML inside foreach statement not rendering even though data is being passed back to view

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I went through the debug and found that the values are being passed but for some reason the property values are not being added to page. I can't figure out why. On submit, data chosen from the form is sent to DisplayProviders.

DisplayProviders then compares the string values to the property names in the list of provider agencies then stores the data found inside TempData. A RedirectToAction occurs and sends the TempData to Index().

The View, after the second request of Index(), then recieves the list of providers. However, even though ViewBag is not null (I went though it in debug) it doesn't add the agency names when I go through it with foreach. Using debug, **I found that the names ARE being passed but the HTML is not being added to the page.**

Please help!

In Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        ViewBag.ListOfProviders = TempData["ProvidersFound"];
        return View();
    }

[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DisplayProviders(string[] area, string[] mode, string[] eligibility)
    {
       var allProviders = repo.GetProviders();

       //Code to narrow down list of providers using the options passed
       //through ajax (area, mode, and eligibility) this part works and
       //provider agencies were found and stored in TempData

        TempData["ProvidersFound"] = providersFound;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Code in View:

```
@model TransportationProvidersDemo.Models.Provider 
@{

    var providersFound = ViewBag.ListOfProviders;

}
<--HTML form here (omitted)-->
<input type="submit" />

<div>

        @if (providersFound != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in providersFound)
            {
                <div>
                    <h3>@item.AgencyName</h3>
                </div>
            }
        }

    </div>
```

And I'm using ajax to send data to DisplayProviders

```
 $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "/Home/DisplayProviders",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  data: { area: areaSelected, mode: modeSelected, eligibility: eligibilitySelected },
                  datatype: "json",
                  traditional: true,
                  success: function (response) {
                      if (response != null) {
                          alert("SUCCESS! Good job!");
                      } else {
                          alert("Something went wrong");
                      }
                  },
                  failure: function (response) {
                      alert("Failure");
                  },
                  error: function (response) {
                      alert("Error");
                  }
              });
```

Comment: TempData is stored in session, I would avoid it if I were you as you'll be tied to that server if you ever need to actually scale.

Comment: The ajax is definitely sending data. The problem is that RedirectToAction is a client side redirect that stores data in session state. You won't get the correct data from the ajax response

Comment: Your code makes no sense. The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page and ajax call NEVER redirect! And you never do anything to update the DOM in the success callback anyway. And setting `TempData` in the `DisplayProviders` method does not change the value of `var providersFound` in the view (it is initially `null` and does not magically change just because you set it on the server). You seem to have a major misunderstanding of what ajax is and what its used for.

Answer (score 0):

can you try passing your found providers list from Tempdata as model in the view object ? like below:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var ListOfProviders = TempData["ProvidersFound"] as (your strongly type list);
    return View(ListOfProviders);
}
```

View:

```
@model List<TransportationProvidersDemo.Models.Provider>

    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div>
                <h3>@item.AgencyName</h3>
            </div>
        }
    }

</div>
```

Comment: I also tried this and it works. Data is passed back to view perfectly just like the way Keith Rousseau suggested answer does. The problem with both approaches is that the HTML inside the foreach statement is not rendering in the cshtml page. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the ViewBag you must be aware that the elements you read from it are of type object so you need to cast them.

View :

```
@model List<TransportationProvidersDemo.Models.Provider>
    @{
         var providersFound = ViewBag.ListOfProviders != null ?
                                  ViewBag.ListOfProviders as List<Providers> : 
                                  null; 
    }
<ommited form here>
    @if (providersFound!= null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div>
                <h3>@item.AgencyName</h3>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that RedirectToAction is a client side redirect that stores data in session state. You won't get the correct data from the ajax response. You should just return the view directly from DisplayProviders instead.

Comment: So I did change it to return to the view directly from DisplayProviders and the data is passed to the view perfectly, however, the html inside the foreach statement is not rendering. Any clue why  this could be?

Comment: My guess is that somehow that providersFound null check is false and not hitting the loop